# Migration to AndroidX causes java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/appcompat/app/NotificationCompat$Builder

Tags: java, dependencies, classnotfoundexception, ros, androidx

In my android application I am using ROS. One of the dependencies that is included with that is `org.ros.android_core:android_10:0.3.3`. I mention this because it seems that there is a problem with one of the classes in this jar file: namely `org/ros/android/NodeMainExecutorService.class`.

The reason for this is that when I run my application, the following error shows up:

```
2019-05-08 11:10:41.980 10740-10747/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
2019-05-08 11:10:42.829 10740-10740/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: robot.fsrt.robotguest, PID: 10740
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/appcompat/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;
    at org.ros.android.NodeMainExecutorService.onStartCommand(NodeMainExecutorService.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3326)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1582)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.appcompat.app.NotificationCompat$Builder" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/robot.fsrt.robotguest-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/robot.fsrt.robotguest-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/robot.fsrt.robotguest-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/robot.fsrt.robotguest-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/robot.fsrt.robotguest-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/robot.fsrt.robotguest-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/robot.fsrt.robotguest-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/robot.fsrt.robotguest-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/robot.fsrt.robotguest-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/robot.fsrt.robotguest-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/robot.fsrt.robotguest-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/robot.fsrt.robotguest-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/robot.fsrt.robotguest-2/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at org.ros.android.NodeMainExecutorService.onStartCommand(NodeMainExecutorService.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3326) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1582) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
```

On line `NodeMainExecutorService.java:214` class `NotificationCompat.Builder` is being instanciated;

```
androidx.appcompat.app.NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new androidx.appcompat.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
```

While the folder `androidx.appcompat.app` does exist(within `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha04`), `NotificationCompat.Builder` is not in there.

> Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "robot.fsrt.robotguest"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion = '28.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation('org.ros.android_core:android_10:[0.3, 0.4)') {
        exclude group: 'junit'
        exclude group: 'xml-apis'
    }
    // e.g. official msgs
    implementation 'org.ros.rosjava_messages:std_msgs:0.5.11'
    implementation 'org.ros.rosjava_messages:sensor_msgs:1.12.7'
    implementation 'org.ros.rosjava_messages:geometry_msgs:1.12.7'
    implementation 'org.ros.rosjava_bootstrap:message_generation:0.3.3'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha04'
    implementation "androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0-alpha04"
    implementation "androidx.core:core:1.1.0-beta01"
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.27.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

So the problem is that `androidx.appcompat.app.NotificationCompat.Builder` that is defined within a ROS library `org.ros.android_core:android_10:0.3.3` could not be found. How can I solve this?

**EDIT:** I found out that `NotificationCompat` is part of another extension library (`androidx.core:core:1.1.0-beta01`) where it is headed in package `androidx.core.app` instead of `androidx.appcompat.app`

**EDIT 2:** I also found out that in an older working version the class was not found either. But it did run on my device...

**EDIT 3:** I found out that the problem occurs when I migrate the code to AndroidX. But I am not sure yet why this issue is caused by this action.

Comment: Hi, were you able to resolve the  issue?

Comment: There's might be a possibility that AGP `4.0.0-beta04` able to fix this issue. There's a fix for `jetifier` see release notes here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/jetifier#1.0.0-beta09

Comment: turns out the fix "for my issue" just to use `jetifier.blacklist` as stated here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/issues/591#issuecomment-619435280

Comment: Someone can help..? I had same issue..